# Node js and Phantom js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, phantomjs, phantomjs-node

I'm looking to scrape a page as an exercise to learn phantomjs however I'm having an issue currently. The image loading is deferred so I'm trying to figure out how I can get phantom js to scroll down and wait for the images to load. SCrolling to the bottom of the page doesnt work so I was thinking of scrolling 100px every 3 seconds until it gets to the bottom of the page. How would I achieve this with?

```
const phantom = require('phantom');

(async function() {

  const instance = await phantom.create();
  const page = await instance.createPage();

  await page.on('onResourceRequested', function(requestData) {
    console.info('Requesting', requestData.url);
  });

  await page.open(<URL>);

  const js = await page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js');

  const data = await page.evaluate(function() {
    // Do something
  });

  page.render('test.pdf');  

  await page.close();
  await instance.exit();
})();
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible as there is no scroll with phantomjs. Render is usually the whole page. So either it's a bug on the page or you have to somehow trigger loaded manually for each image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS does support "scrolling", there is a page property `scrollPosition` which can probably used like this:

```
await page.property('scrollPosition', { top: 300, left: 0 });
```

You can change `scrollPosition` dynamically, increasing it within time, which should trigger callbacks responsible for image load.

Here's [an example](https://gist.github.com/jmsdnns/f73921dcaf8cdd3ce570b7dcc669c6a2) in raw PhantomJS script showing the technique to go down Twitter's timeline.

Comment: I ended up using this in combination with a waiting function which scrolls down until it hits the bottom of the page.

Comment: @ElmosGotAGun can you please show me how ?  it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-webshot](https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot) based on phantom.js in order to render pdf as well. It has many configuration. One you need is **renderDelay** to delay screenshotting and **shotOffset** to scroll where you want.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const phantom = require('phantom');

// Scrolls the page till new content is available
async function scrollPage(page) {
    const currentContentLength = (await page.property('content')).length;
    await page.evaluate(function () {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    });
    await wait(Math.max(5000, 10000 * Math.random()));
    const nextContentLength = (await page.property('content')).length;
    if (currentContentLength != nextContentLength) {
        console.log("Scrolling page:", await page.property('url'), "for more content");
        await scrollPage(page);
    }
}

// Scrolls the page and gets the page content using PhantomJS
async function getPageData(pageUrl, shouldScrollPage) {
    const instance = await phantom.create();
    const page = await instance.createPage();
    await page.open(pageUrl);
    if (shouldScrollPage) {
        await scrollPage(page);
    }
    const pageContent = await page.property('content');
    await page.close();
    await instance.exit();
    return pageContent;
};
```